# Is there a technical term for a SQL query's WHERE clause?

Tags: sql

Is there a technical term for the WHERE clause of a SQL query? A word like Condition, Criteria, Restriction, etc.?

Comment: It is restriction. select is a selection, IIRC.

Comment: @wildplasser: any references?

Comment: Codd & Date, I presume? Oh it seems I had them mixed up (or Jimmy_keen has them mixed up) Yes: it was {project, restrict}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using relational algebra terms, it's [*selection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_%28relational_algebra%29) (not to confuse with `select`, which is [*projection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28relational_algebra%29)).

Answer (score 2):

As SQL is an implementation of a relational algebra, the WHERE condition is called **selection** (not to be confused with the SELECT part which implemenets projection and renames). For more information about the term in the scope of relational algebra, please refer to the excellent [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_%28relational_algebra%29).

Answer (score 1):

Reduction of the number of tuples (rows) is called *restriction*. Reduction of the number of attributes (columns) is called *projection*. (this is the original Codd/Date terminology, later Date started using the term "SQL Databases" for not so truly relational DBMSes)

Answer (score 0):

In the [SQL grammar specifications](http://savage.net.au/SQL/), the WHERE clause is known as a ... `where clause`.

What most people mean, however, is the meat of a where clause, the `boolean value expressions` that define the restriction on the number of SELECTed rows.  That is specified in the grammar as the `search condition`.